# Find difference between now and a file's last change time in PHP

Tags: php

I have a file called "file.txt".
I get its last change time with this:

```
$lastTime = filemtime("file.txt");
```

Then I make

```
$lastDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime( $lastTime ));
$todaysDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('now'));
```

Then I substract lastDate from todaysDate and find the difference.
Is there a quicker way to do this?

I don't want to check whether the difference of seconds is >= 86400 or not.

For example the difference between these two dates must be "**1**".

```
2013-03-31 10:00
2013-03-30 19:00
```

If i check for the difference of seconds I will have 54K seconds, which is smaller than 86400 seconds.

Comment: So you want to check the difference in days ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Yes I want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get the difference in seconds, then convert to days and round the result.

```
$diff = time()-filemtime("file.txt");
$days = round($diff/86400);
```

You could also use `floor` or `ceil` in place of `round` depending on exactly how you want to handle partial days.

Comment: As I noted in question, I need the difference of the days not the seconds.

Comment: In what way does this not cater to that requirement?

Comment: I assume one of those rare days which doesn't consist of seconds. Never seen one, but I can't rule them out, there where 10 of the buggers in 1582 and we need to be prepared!

Comment: Because my design takes calendar days into consideration. The difference between these two dates should be one day. "2013-03-31 10:00" "2013-03-30 19:00"

Comment: @trante The code above works for the example you provided, if you have other "format", just follow the logic behind this answer, example: `$diff = round((strtotime("2013-03-31 10:00") - strtotime("2013-03-30 19:00"))/86400);
echo $diff;`